# The state of a functional component does not change very well

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a domain integrated search site now and I need to animate the TLD part of the design that the designer gave me.

However, when entering the keyword to be searched by the functional component, the state did not change while the class component was changed.

### Code

#### functional component

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

import './SearchBarTLD.scss';

const tldList:string[] = [
  '.com',
  '.co.kr',
  '.se',
  '.me',
  '.xyz',
  '.kr',
  '.dev',
  '.xxx',
  '.rich',
  '.org',
  '.io',
  '.shop',
  '.ga',
  '.gg',
  '.net'
];

const SearchBarTLD = () => {
  const [ selectIndex, setSelectIndex ] = React.useState(0);

  const changeIndex = () => {
    if (selectIndex === 14) {
      setSelectIndex(0)
    } else {
      setSelectIndex(selectIndex + 1)
    }
  }
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => changeIndex(), 1500);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  })
  const renderList = () =>{
    return tldList.map((tld:string, index:number) => {
      return (
        <span 
          className={
            classNames(
              "SearchBarTLD__tld", {
                "SearchBarTLD__tld--visual": selectIndex === index
              }
            )
          }
          key={tld}
        >
          {tldList[index]}
        </span>
      )
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="SearchBarTLD">
      {renderList()}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchBarTLD;
```

#### class components

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

import './SearchBarTLD.scss';

export interface SearchBarTLDProps {

}

export interface SearchBarTLDState {
  selectIndex: number,
  tldList: string[]
}

class SearchBarTLD extends React.Component<SearchBarTLDProps, SearchBarTLDState> {
  state: SearchBarTLDState;
  intervalId: any;

  constructor(props: SearchBarTLDProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      selectIndex: 0,
      tldList: [
        '.com',
        '.co.kr',
        '.se',
        '.me',
        '.xyz',
        '.kr',
        '.dev',
        '.xxx',
        '.rich',
        '.org',
        '.io',
        '.shop',
        '.ga',
        '.gg',
        '.net'
      ]
    };
    this.intervalId = 0;
  }

  changeIndex() {
    const { selectIndex } = this.state;
    if (selectIndex === 14) {
      this.setState({selectIndex: 0});
    } else {
      this.setState({selectIndex: selectIndex + 1});
    }
  }

  renderList = () =>{
    const { selectIndex, tldList } = this.state;
    return tldList.map((tld:string, index:number) => {
      return (
        <span 
          className={
            classNames(
              "SearchBarTLD__tld", {
                "SearchBarTLD__tld--visual": selectIndex === index
              }
            )
          }
          key={tld}
        >
          {tldList[index]}
        </span>
      )
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => this.changeIndex(), 1500);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId)
  }


  render() { 
    return (
      <div className="SearchBarTLD">
        {this.renderList()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBarTLD;
```

---

The results of the functional component and the results of the class component are shown below.

#### funcational component

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/28648915/56777865-8c0cf100-680e-11e9-93ad-cb7b59cd54e9.gif

#### class component

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/28648915/56777941-e4dc8980-680e-11e9-8a47-be0a14a44ed9.gif

Can you guys tell me why this happens?

Comment: I believe your issue may be around updating the state without the `prevState`. This `this.setState({selectIndex: selectIndex + 1});` should be `this.setState(prevState ->  ({selectIndex: prevState,selectIndex + 1}));`. This handles the async updates.

Comment: See this documentation for details https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: Well, if you use hooks as useState, is not it an async update?

Comment: Yeah, both are async so if your depending on the previous value you need to use a functional update. Hook equiv is here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates